# Symfony 4 - Endpoint for uploaded files

Tags: php, symfony

I've developped an simple FileUploader Service based on the Symfony documentation found here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

My app is just a simple API called inside a Ionic Mobile App.

What I want to know is what is the best practices to give access to my uploaded images.

For exemple, I have an Sport entity `App\Entity\Sport` that stores an image:
When i request `GET /api/sports/` I want to send as response the full url to the image so it can be displayed inside the mobile app (e.g. http://symfony/api/public/uploads/sports/XXXXX.jpg)

Maybe I'm overcomplicating the issue but do I need to make an `GET /public/uploads/sports/{id}` as an endpoint to get my pictures ? because if possible i would like to have the pictures instantly available after the `GET /api/sports` and not having to query another time for the picture aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just simply add the URL into a field of the JSON response object, where you can access the the picture directly? IMHO there is nothing wrong with that.

I find https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards a good reference to start with if it comes to these kind of decisions.

Comment: Really interresting link you just gave me, will read all of this and come up with my solution, might post it aswell for reference. Thanks a lot <3